# Remove custom stopwords and phrases using quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda

I have my stopword list which I would like to use it to remove specific phrases from text:

```
   #dummy text
    df2 <- c("hi my name is Ann and code code all the time! However not after that I would like")

mystopwords <- c("hi", "code code", "not after that")
```

I use this option:

```
myDfm <- df2 %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = c(stopwords(source = "smart"), mystopwords)) %>%
  tokens_wordstem() %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = c(1, 3)) %>%
  dfm()
```

but when I check the frequency of bigram or trigram they didn't removed just stemmed.

Is there anything wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by using `phrase()` function when you are using the list of stop-phrases.

It works like this:

```
library(quanteda)
df2 <- c("hi my name is Ann and code code all the time! However not after that I would like")

mystopwords <- c("hi", "code code", "not after that")

df2 %>% tokens %>% 
  tokens_remove(pattern = phrase(mystopwords), valuetype = 'fixed')

## tokens from 1 document.
## text1 :
##  [1] "my"      "name"    "is"      "Ann"     "and"     "all"     "the"     "time"    "!"       "However" "I"       "would"  
## [13] "like"
```

You can get the detailed information about how to work with multiword expressions in **quanteda** here:
https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/phrase.html