# Remove 2 stopwords lists with Quanteda package R

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, stop-words, quanteda

I'm working with quanteda package on a corpus dataframe, and here is the basic code i use :

```
library(quanteda)

fmsi_des <- dfm(corpus_des, remove=stopwords("spanish"), verbose=TRUE,
                remove_punct=TRUE, remove_numbers=TRUE)
```

However, i have another stopowords list as a data frame, called stpw, that i'd like to take into account.

I tried :

```
fmsi_des <- dfm(corpus_des, remove=stopwords("spanish","stpw"), verbose=TRUE,
                remove_punct=TRUE, remove_numbers=TRUE)
```

> Error in stopwords("spanish", "stpw") : unused argument ("stpw")

Then i created a list with the stopwords of "spanish" + the stopwords of stpw :

```
all_stops <- c("bogota","vias","medellin","valle","departamento",stopwords("spanish"))

fmsi_des <- dfm(corpus_des, remove=stopwords("all_stops"), verbose=TRUE,
                remove_punct=TRUE, remove_numbers=TRUE)
```

> Error in stopwords("all_stops") : no stopwords available for 'all_stops'

I also created a txt file with my stopwords, in order to try that :

```
library(tm)

stopwords = readLines('stpw.txt') 
x  = fd$contract_description        
x  =  removeWords(x,stopwords)

des <- subset(x, !is.na(x))
corpus_des <- corpus(des$fd.contract_description)
fmsi_des <- dfm(corpus_des, remove=stopwords("spanish"), verbose=TRUE,
                remove_punct=TRUE, remove_numbers=TRUE)
```

> Warning message:
> In readLines("stp.txt") : Incomplete final line found in 'stpw.txt'

> Error in gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\b(%s)\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :
> incorrect regular expression '(*UCP)\b(bogota|vias|medellin|valle|departamento|+)\b'
> In addition : Warning message:
> In gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\b(%s)\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE),  :
> PCRE pattern compilation error
> 'nothing to repeat'
> at '+)\b'

Comment: Perhaps this approach may help [Quanteda phrase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54550990/remove-custom-stopwords-and-phrases-using-quanteda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where knowing the value of return objects in R is the key to obtaining the result you want.  Specifically, you need to know what `stopwords()` returns, as well as what it is expected as its first argument.

`stopwords(language = "sp")` returns a character vector of Spanish stopwords, using the default `source = "snowball"` list.  (See `?stopwords` for full details.)

So if you want to remove the default Spanish list *plus* your own words, you concatenate the returned character vector with additional elements.  This is what you have done in creating `all_stops`.

So to remove `all_stops` -- and here, using the quanteda v3 suggested usage -- you simply do the following:

```
fmsi_des <- corpus_des %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_remove(pattern = all_stops) %>%
    dfm()
```

Comment: Unfortunately i still have the stopwords in the output :(

Comment: No my bad, i was trying on the wrong data for my topic command. It works, thanks !